# How to do state operations in function in react without class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, constructor, state

this is my React worksection.js file and its function made instead of class

```
export default function WorkSection() {
```

now i need to do here constructor to initialise state and do function operations which i'll call on button click

```
 return (
    <div className={classes.section}>
      <GridContainer justify="center">
        <GridItem cs={12} sm={12} md={8}>
          <h2 className={classes.title}>Work with us</h2>
          <h4 className={classes.description}>
            BAIOS BAY LLP is looking for collaborations with you, Contact us
            today !
          </h4>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <GridContainer>
              <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                <CustomInput
                  labelText="Your Name"
                  id="name"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  defaultValue={this.state.name}
                  formControlProps={{
                    fullWidth: true
                  }}
                /> </GridItem>   </GridContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is my form where i am submitting name and will add button click so how can i initialise state and functions to call onclick functions where
my functions are as :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    name : ''}
  }
handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.id]: event.target.value

  });
}

handleClick = event => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.id]: event.target.checked

  });
}

handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this.state.username === '') {
    this.showMessage('Info', "Username is empty");
    return;
  }
  }
```

i need to place this function and i did it with class worksection but how to do it with export default function Worksection()

Comment: https://javascriptplayground.com/refactoring-to-react-hooks/ - make sure you're on a recent version of React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default function WorkSection() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => {
    axios
      .get(" 
...................... my code ...............
```

and my input form is :

```
 return (
    <div className={classes.section}>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <Input
                  name="Name"
                  placeholder="Name"
                  inputRef={register}
                  fullWidth={true}
                />
                <Input
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  fullWidth={true}
                  inputRef={register({ required: true })}
                />
                <Input
                  name="contact"
                  placeholder="Contact"
                  fullWidth={true}
                  inputRef={register({ required: true })}
                />         
                <Input
                  name="description"
                  placeholder="Message"
                  multiline={true}
                  fullWidth={true}
                  inputRef={register({ required: true })}
                />
               <button className="btnColor" justify="center" type="submit">
                  Send Message
                </button>
              </GridItem>
            </GridContainer>
          </form>
</div>
```

Basically i used

```
   inputRef={register}
```

and other part as satated above. 
Right code , worked for me ~

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're probably looking for called [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). They allow you to use state management in your functional components. They're cool because they're lightweight in compare with class components.

First, import `useState` function from `react`:

`import { useState } from 'react'`

Then, before your return, add these lines:
`const [name, setName] = useState('');`

The first argument here is the name of your state property, and the second one is the function to change it.

So, instead of this:

```
handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.id]: event.target.value
  });
}
```

Write this:

```
handleChange = event => {
  setName(event.target.value);
}
```

If you want to make it more complex, you can rewrite your hook from this:

`const [name, setName] = useState('');`

to this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  name: '',
  checked: false,
});
```

Comment: thanks @westfalensgod for this contribution, basically i used hooks !

Comment: [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started) this guided me a lot.